# PayPal IPNs for subscriptions with a trial period

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have read the extensive discussions on this topic here and they are quite informative but there is one issue that is largely left untouched: What happens when the developer offers a trial period?

Say I have a subscription button that charges **2 dollars a year** but I'm offering a trial period at **0 dollars for a month**.

- What are the key IPN messages I expect to receive and in what order? My tests seem to indicate that I only receive **subscr_signup** during the trial period
- Does a subscribed user get automatically charged if they don't cancel before the trial period is over?
- Does this scenario mean users are effectively paying for 11
  months?

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. Yes. 2. No. They get the free period plus the next twelve months, for which they pay,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is hidden in the comments so I'm posting it here to highlight it.

**From user207421** [posted on Aug 24 '19 at 9:37]:

> 1. Correct. 2. Yes. 2. No. They get the free period plus the next twelve months, for which they pay,